# How to make a bat file that opens chrome profile shortcut and then visits url?

Tags: batch-file

I have created a chrome shortcut on my desktop that links to a different profile but how do i open the shortcut in bat file? This is what i tried.

```
@echo off
:loop
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" -incognito http://www.youtube.com 
timeout 60
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
goto loop
```

But it says that directory profile 2 cannot be found. I would like bat file to open a specific profile then visit a url can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you give the full path to the profile directory?

Comment: i don't know what you mean i think that is the full path to the profile directory i copy and paste from the target field?